# Populating field values in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know the best way to assign a generated value for model field in a django form. Here is the code for what I need to implement the logic.

**Model:**

```
class Booking:
    number = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

What I need to do is, store the combination of `number + category` in `ref` field when model is saved. I know there are two methods called `save()` and `clean()` available for this. But I'm not sure which one is the best to use.

Thanks.

Comment: clean just cleans the data and doesnt  store them to database, the thing you are trying to needs to be done in save() method.

Comment: Can't I assign the generated value in the cleaned_data['ref'] dict in the clean method since all fields are available at that time?

Comment: Why do you need to store this at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to use it with generated number appended. Here I mentioned the simplified code.

Comment: Well, as Exprator says, the best place to do this is in the save method. It shouldn't be in the form at all, since you are not expecting the user to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom `save` function in the `Booking` model.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ref = "%s%s" % (self.number, self.category)
        super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```